# Extracting a JSON from an HTTR cURL request in R

Tags: r, httr, rcurl

I have a CURL requests that I've converted to run in R using the `httr` package. The request looks like this:

```
person <- GET(
"https://api.secure.com/v4/id/123456?$expand=customFields",
accept_json(),
add_headers(Accept = 'application/json',
Authorization = 'Basic [API KEY]')
)
```

And returns a response that looks like this:

```
Response [https://api.secure.com/v4/id/123456?$expand=customFields]
  Date: 2021-08-06 16:48
  Status: 200
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
  Size: 18.9 kB
{
  "Id": 123456,
  "firstName": "Joe",
  "lastName": "Smith",
  "middleName": null,
  "suffix": null,
  "title": "Mr.",
  "contactMode": "Person",
  "organizationContactCommonName": null,
  "organizationContactOfficialName": null,
...
```

I have two questions:

1. How do I expand the results to see the entirety of the response (How do I see the JSON return beyond the `...` because there's definitely more data there)
2. How do I extract just the JSON part? I don't need the Response or Date or Status or any of that stuff. I just need everything starting with that first `{`

Answer (score 0):

Use `content(person)` to get the body of the response. See the `?httr::content` help page for more info. Check out the [getting started vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/httr/vignettes/quickstart.html) if you are new to the pacakge.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but running `content(person)` doesn't seem to return it in JSON form, which is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Well, did you check out the `?content` help page? There are lots of options there. If you don't actually want to parse the JSON data and you want it as a string for some reason, you can use `content(person, as="text")`. But by default it saves you a step by parsing it for you when JSON data is returned.